# how can i set the vscode to input parameters from debug console

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I debug the code by vscode,  the console immediately print "hello  and  ", 
program exit 0, lead to that i can't input a1 and a2, so how can i set the vscode ?

The go code as follows,

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
    fmt.Println("Please enter your firstname and lastname")
    var a1,a2 string
    fmt.Scan(&a1,&a2)       // it don't stop to wait my input data.
    fmt.Println("hello ",a1," and ",a2)
}
```

Comment: You could open the `launch.json` (gear icon), and you could add a `console` property, something like `"console": "internalConsole"`, or with `"integratedTerminal"`. It's not supported for me so I couldn't try it. Read more about it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: I tried it, but there is no property "console" in launch.json, so sad, 100000 why in my brain.